# Unable to retrieve model attribute from view in spring mvc portlet

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

This is part of spring mvc portlet and we are trying to retrieve a model attribute from the view layer in the controller,but it is showing as null.
We tried using both `modelAttribute` as well as `commandName` with bean name and form input fields with path names corresponding to bean attributes.

> View jsp

```
<form:form id="empForm" modelAttribute="empBean"  action="${createEmpURL}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

<form:hidden path="empId"></form:hidden>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="empName">Employee Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <form:input type="text" id="empName" path="empName"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="grade">Grade</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <form:input type="text" id="grade" path="grade"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
            <input id="validateNewEmployeeButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

> Controller class

```
    @ActionMapping  
    public void createEmp(@ModelAttribute("empBean") Employee emp, BindingResult bindingResult,ActionRequest req,ActionResponse res)
{
    System.out.println("------------->"+emp);

}
```

> Bean class

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>,Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long empId;
private String empName;
private String grade;

public long getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public Employee() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setEmpId(long empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}

public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}

public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(String grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}


@Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o) {

        return (int) (this.getEmpId() - o.getEmpId());

    }
 }

Update
```

Used this URL for action URL:`<portlet:actionURL var="createEmpURL" escapeXml="false">
</portlet:actionURL>`

Any clues on what could be possibly missing would be helpful?Please comment for any further details needed.

Comment: any error you are getting ? what is url you are mapping?

Comment: @shantaram_t No errors per se.I am mapping the form to an action URL.Will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your controller method as

1. Add url `@ActionMapping(value="/someUrl")`
2. Try to print binding errors using `BindingResult`

   ```
   @ActionMapping(value="/someUrl")
   public void createEmp(@ModelAttribute("empBean") Employee emp, BindingResult bindingResult,ActionRequest req,ActionResponse res)
   {
       for( FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors() )
           System.out.println(fieldError.getField() +" : "+fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
       System.out.println("------------->"+emp);
   }
   ```

**Updated:-**
try to create URL as

```
<portlet:actionURL var="createEmpURL" name="createEmp" escapeXml="false">
</portlet:actionURL>
```

**update 2**  from this link https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/32472440#_19_message_32690931

> Hi
>    I have used following tag in liferay-portlet.xml file its working successfully..

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

**liferay-portlet.xml as follows**

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>welcome</portlet-name>
    <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
</portlet>
```

Hope this help...

Comment: I had tried bindingResult.getFieldErrors() but it was empty

Comment: what about action url ?

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: The problem still persists.The correct controller method is reached,hence I do not think url should be an issue

Comment: Nothing on server console!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151354/discussion-between-shantaram-t-and-shivam-aggarwal).

Comment: Thanks Shanta! Namespacing was causing this issue